# Ayuda reporte dompdf version 0.7.0

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy generando un reporte en pdf con dompdf, funciona a la perfección el tema es el siguiente, como puedo hacer para que cuando el campo imagen del reporte el recordset está vacio me muestre una imagen alternativa, por ejemplo sin_imagen.gif y no me aparezca el recuadro Image not found or type unknown

Answer (score 0):

podrías probar con "file_exist"... este fragmento es como lo uso para un proyecto que estoy armando actualmente...

```
$url = "http://localhost/PHPizza/imagenes/sabores/";
$imagen= "muzzarella.png"; // como ejemplo

if (file_exists($url.$imagen)) {
    echo $url . $imagen;
} else {
    echo $url . 'no_imagen.png';
}
```

www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-exists.php

Comment: $url = 'http://localhost/nuevo/imagenes/';
$imagen= '$url.$row["strImagen"].'; // como ejemplo

if (file_exists($imagen)) {
    echo $url . $imagen;
} else {
    echo $url.'sin_foto.gif';
};

Comment: Lo hice de esa manera pero adonde está la imagen me aparece $url.$row["strImagen"], no se como hacer para que se vea la imagen y soy nuevo en esto, gracias por contestar